# File to import not found or unreadable: using @import with sass

Tags: sass

I am trying to set up a project using sass, I have a style.scss in my root folder and then I have a folder called modules, in which I've added the file I want to import(with sass no csss import). I used underscore like this :

_reset.css and then in style.scss I import with the @import command :

@import "modules/reset".

I have tried to update Ruby, also tried different ways to rename the file, with or without _, with extension .scss.css also with .sass extension but every time I try I get this error :

error style.scss (Line 83: File to import not found or unreadable: modules/reset.
Load path: /path/to/root/folder)

I've checked and I have no typo erros, also I looked here and in google but I can only find ppl having this problem using compass, but I don't want to use compass for this project, I just want to use vanilla sass.

I had ruby 1.8.7 then updated to the new version, did all the updates and cleaned up every thing but still the error is there, and is becoming quite frustrating.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your file/directory structure.

Comment: is very simple : root that contains style.scss and the modules folder which contains the _reset.scss file

Comment: looks like he cannot find the file, but I am sure is in the correct folder

Comment: Double check the contents of the file you're importing, there may be an encoding issue here.

Comment: I tried, I deleted all the content inside the reset file, now is a blank file but still the same error, also I tried on a linux machine, I run mac, and the same error, this is driving me crazy today.

Comment: The file is called reset.scss not reset.css sorry for the typo.

Comment: I've removed all the ruby versions and installed the latest one, 2.0.0p247 and still the same problem, I removed all the content inside the file and still the same problem, this now is becoming frustrating any help would be very appreciated, I googled all the first 10 pages and only people with the same problem but using compass, I cannot find a solution for using only sass.

Comment: After going crazy for a couple of hours, I found out the solution, is not sass or ruby, but it's sublimetext2 that does change the file name from _reset.scss to _reset.scss.css and the import cannot find the file, I used phpstorm and this does not happens, so now it works :D